# How to fix page to be shown correct in google cache

Tags: html, caching, fullpage.js

Hay, I have problem with google cache. I want the homepage of my site in google cache will be shown correct and not broken, like the source. this is the source:
https://www.fnx.co.il.

the cahed page is [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FKJV1hxgkQYJ:https://www.fnx.co.il/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=il#110).

I googled it and I found answers to check if links are up-to-date, or to check reltive links. it is not the problem. even what is missing is font files. the site uses fullpage.js to inital sections, and I think the problem is that google adds it own elements, that disrupt the initialization of page. page without fullpage like search results are shown correct.

is there way to prevent from google to add its elements to the page, or another solution that will make the cached page look good?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you have an error in your normal page that you would need to fix first:

> fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing it multiple times!

That means you are initialising fullPage.js multiple times and that's why scrolling down in a Macbook trackpad (or some other kinetic scrolling devices) will scroll more than one section at a time.

Make sure to fix that first.

> the site uses fullpage.js to inital sections, and I think the problem is that google adds it own elements, that disrupt the initialization of page. page without fullpage like search results are shown correct.

It doesn't seem to be the issue. The fullpage.js site is displayed almost correctly (besides the top margin issue) [in Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BiLO_D_Oz5wJ:https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/+&cd=1&hl=es&ct=clnk&gl=es#page1)

I would try to use the latest fullPage.js version (3.0.5) and then see if you still have the issue.